# ObservableCollection<T> initialize a new instance or remove and add

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection bound to some DataGrid. In some cases, when I invoke some command by clicking the button, I need to remove all elements from the collection and add a new once (there could be a few elements, but a plenty of them also, probably not more than 1000). When doing that, is it better to initialize a new instance of the ObservableCollection with new values, something like this (warning - this way the PropertyChanged event needs to be invoked):

```
collection = new ObservableCollection<T>(newValues);
```

or it is better to clear all elements and then add a new ones like this (since ObservableCollection doesn't contain a method AddRange):

```
collection.Clear();
foreach (T value in newValues)
{
    collection .Add(value );
}
```

I'm asking because of a speed effect and an amount of memory that is being consumed when there are a lot of elements in case.

Comment: The general rule is not to worry about optimizing until optimizing is required. From what I understand, you are not combating any issue at the moment, but just asking what's best practice? In that case, why not use the easiest, most straightforward approach?

Comment: You probably could detach the collection temporary from the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque Yes, I'm just asking for a best practice. I just made a little test for integer types, it is about 5 times faster initializing a new instance (and it's easier). The memory consuption is just for question. But since my whole application is using just 120MB of memory, I'll probably stick to that.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I don't find this useful since I'm using MVVM pattern. Cannot reach view from the viewModel, if I'm not mistaking